# Elastic search sort by one of the single nested doc key

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

i have docs which look like these :-

"_source": {

```
      "product_name": "p2",
      "m_p": [
        {
          "m_id": "m2",
          "price": 100
        },
        {
          "m_id": "m4",
          "price": 101
        }
      ]
    }
```

and

"_source": {

```
     "product_name": "p1",
      "m_p": [
        {
          "m_id": "m1",
          "price": 50
        },
        {
          "m_id": "m2",
          "price": 55
        },
        {
          "m_id": "m3",
          "price": 55
        },
        {
          "m_id": "m5",
          "price": 65
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now i need to sort these based on the price of given(from external source) m_id and p_id pair.
for example the external service gives that for p1-m2 , and p2-m4
so the query should have sorted products based on the price of p1 as 55(m2 selling at 55) and price of p2 as 101(m4 selling at 101).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [nested sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html) to sort by a value stored in a nested field. Moreover, you can use the `nested_filter` field to sort by the content of the field just in the documents you care about.

As in the nested filter you can only filter on properties of the nested documents, you will have to store the `product_name` in every nested document if you want to filter by both `product_name` and `m_id` while sorting.

With these settings

```
{
   "mappings": {
      "test": {
         "properties": {
            "m_p": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                   "price": {"type": "integer"},
                   "product_name": {"type": "string"},
                   "m_id": {"type": "string"}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and indexing documents with this format

```
{      "product_name": "p2",
       "m_p": [
        {
          "m_id": "m2",
          "product_name": "p2",
          "price": 100
        },
        {
          "m_id": "m4",
          "product_name": "p2",
          "price": 101
        }
      ]
}
```

you can use the following query to order according to both `product_name` and `m_id`

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "sort": {
      "m_p.price": {
         "nested_path": "m_p",
         "order": "asc",
         "nested_filter": {
            "or": [
               {
                  "and": [
                     { "term": { "m_p.product_name": "p1" }},
                     { "term": { "m_p.m_id": "m2" }}
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "and": [
                     { "term": { "m_p.product_name": "p2" }},
                     { "term": { "m_p.m_id": "m4" }}
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ur script is sorting based on the minimum of each docs, but not taking price corresponding to that m_id ...ie it take the minimum of first doc as 50 and 100 for second and sort but not sorting according to prices 55 and 101

Comment: is your `m_p` field analyzed with data type `nested`?

Comment: I updated the answer for clarity - I tested this on Elasticsearch 2.1.1 and it works as expected.

Comment: Please consider confirming the answer as the correct one, if this solves your issue ;)